# MySQL multiple joins being slow

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've got a table with the following structure:

[image: db structure]

I've got all my primary keys correct and every int & date column has an index, and `(playerId, groupId)` in `player_groups` is an unique index. All tables are using InnoDB, and the relations you see are also references in InnoDB.

Full database source, with data, roughly similar to the examples I'll demonstrate below: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kzf89occlq4legy/bf4_performance.sql

Queries:

- Query #1: `SELECT * FROM playerkills ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 300;`
- Query #2: `SELECT p.playerName AS player, p2.playerName AS target, w.weaponName AS weapon, date, headshot, s.serverName AS server FROM playerkills JOIN players p ON playerkills.playerId = p.playerId JOIN players p2 ON playerkills.targetId = p2.playerId JOIN weapons w ON playerkills.weaponId = w.weaponId JOIN servers s ON playerkills.serverId = s.serverId ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 300;`

Performance on my own machine, which has a lot of resources:

- Query #1: 0.0016 sec
- Query #2: 1.3050 sec

Performance on the live database host, which has considerably less resources:

- Query #1: 0.046 sec
- Query #2: 1.297 sec

I'm afraid something is highly impacting the performance as it works fine without any `JOIN` statements.
Can anyone shed some more light on this?

ps (**edit**). Also possibly important to add: This database is in live being updated every few seconds, so the results of the queries cannot be cached the same way as queries on static data could be.

**EDIT 2:** Profiling on the static version (on `localhost`) gave me this picture:

[image: db profile]

Output of `EXPLAIN`:

[image: db explain]

Comment: the more tables you join the slower it gets, can improve via proper indexing but will not be as fast as single table select

Comment: @user2864740 Added the more detailed data per request.

Comment: You are joining `p2` with `playerkills` on `targetId`, which does not have an index. This means that a full table scan have to be made. Try to add an index to `playerkills` and show the output of `EXPLAIN` again.

Comment: I have just double-checked and `playerkills`.`targetId` does have an index.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of those cases where a subselect may help your cause.  Rather than joining all those tables to the full playerkills table, you can subselect your last 300 player kills and then join based on that.  So something like:

```
SELECT
  p.playerName AS player,
  p2.playerName AS target,
  w.weaponName AS weapon,
  pk.date AS date,
  pk.headshot AS headshot,
  s.serverName AS server
FROM
(SELECT * FROM playkills ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 300) AS pk
JOIN players p
  ON pk.playerId = p.playerId
JOIN players p2
  ON pk.targetId = p2.playerId
JOIN weapons w
  ON pk.weaponId = w.weaponId
JOIN servers s
  ON pk.serverId = s.serverId
```

Comment: It needs another `ORDER BY date DESC` at the end, but apart from that this one is very fast again! Thanks a lot, though I thought that MySQL always would do the optimization for you, given that you yourself are doing the correct indices, etc. Maybe this is one of the edge cases?

Comment: @skiwi The way that MySQL generates its execution plan may often times differ from what one might expect (particularly in sometimes ignoring indexes that are available for use).  This however is not one of those times as `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` are in essence applied to the result of the main query.  In your original query, this meant that you needed to join all the records across all tables, order them all by date and then limit the result set.  While generally subselects are not great for performance, there are case like these where limiting data set before joining is proper approach.

Comment: This is just bad query planning on MySQL's part. The order-by/limit *can* be moved under RA rules. However, I can't argue with the practical result.

Comment: Well fair enough, I now know where to take note off. The `JOIN`s don't actually limit anything at the moment anyway, maybe I should look one day into `MEMORY` table implementations as they're essentially lookup tables.